# How to get "Open Command Window Here" while clicking on exe not on parent folder?

Tags: windows-7

One can open dos command window by shift-clicking on a folder but I'd rather like to do so by shift clicking on exe INSIDE the folder.

Any registry hack to do so like this one but on exe instead of folder:

http://www.networksteve.com/?p=2308

Comment: `Shift-click` does not open a command window for me. Are you sure you haven't installed some software to achieve this?

Comment: On windows 7. On XP I think you must hack registry see here http://www.networksteve.com/index.php/2010/03/open-a-command-prompt-from-any-folder/

Comment: I mean right-shift-click rather

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Notepad to paste this into an empty .REG file, then save and double-click the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exefile]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exefile\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exefile\shell\cmdhere]
@="Command Prompt Here"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exefile\shell\cmdhere\command]
@="cmd.exe"
```

(it adds a context menu entry for executables; tested on XP)

Comment: Great thanks it works perfect even on windows 7 :)