# How to add an explorer context menu for a file extension?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu, shell-extensions

I was inspired by [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/129755/how-to-get-open-command-window-here-while-clicking-on-exe-not-on-parent-folder) to try the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.sln]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.sln\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.sln\shell\countlines]
@="countlines"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.sln\shell\countlines\command]
@="c:\\countlines\\countlines.exe" %1
```

This should be adding a context menu item named "countlines" that runs the "countlines.exe" command, but it doesn't work.

How does one add a context menu entry for a given file extension?

Comment: Here's thinking that this is a dupe of the question linked to. OP should be adding this to that question via an edit, no?

Comment: @marcusw: doesn't appear a duplicate to me; if anything it's a more general case (in which case the other question can be closed as a duplicate of this one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of the **`.sln`** key should be something like **`VisualStudio.Launcher.sln`**. That's called the program ID (ProgID)  and it's the key you should edit to change the context menu:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\shell]
```

A ProgID key always takes precedence, so any changes made to the extension key will be ignored when a ProgID is present. ProgIDs are mainly used to group extensions into logical file types.

Comment: @efotinis: slightly unrelated, but is that why jpegs are unaffected [by these registry tweaks](http://superuser.com/questions/133188/disable-thumbnails-in-windows-xp/133220#133220) but avis are?

Comment: Do you know where to look up the ProgID for a given extension?

Answer (score 0):

This article helps in creating context menus for specific file types.

https://blog.sverrirs.com/2014/05/creating-cascading-menu-items-in.html